# Jquery, get an array of text()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, split

I am trying to get and array of text after using the text function, having a ul list like

```
<ul>
  <li>one
    <ul>
      <li>one one</li>
      <li>one two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

then get something like

```
['one', 'one one', 'one two']
```

Comment: Please post the jQuery you've tried.

Comment: I was working with jstree, cause of that I dont paster my code cause it is too long, however, all ideas from here helpe a lot on how to solve my issue. Thanks to all

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
var array = $('li').map(function(){
               return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get();
```

http://api.jquery.com/map/

Demo Fiddle `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/EC4yq/

Comment: You may want to chain a call to `.toArray()`.

Comment: what does `get()` method do? BTW We can do `$('li').toArray().map((li) => {  return li.innerText.trim(); })`

Comment: @mangatinanda @TrueWill i think `.get` and `.toArray` do the same thing https://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
$("li").map(function(){ return this.innerText })
```

or this:

```
$("li").toArray().map(function(i){ return i.innerText })
```

Answer (score 9):

You just want to get the text from all the li's?

```
var resultArray = [];

$('li').each(function(){
    resultArray.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Several of the answers ignore the OP's desired format.

This will give you what you want.

```
$('li').map(function(){
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    $clone.children('*').remove();
    return $.trim($clone.text());
}).get()
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pE9PR/

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
var children = $(listholder).children();
var array = [];
var i = 0;
$.each(children, function(key, value){
array.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer actually not answer the question, OP want `firstChild` text

```
['one', 'one one', 'one two']
```

but accepted answer give `textContent`

```
['one\n\none one\none two', 'one one', 'one two']
```

There are two method to answer, first using jQuery `contents()`

```js
var array = $('li').map(function() {
  return $(this).contents()[0].textContent.trim()
}).get();

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one
    <ul>
      <li>one one</li>
      <li>one two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

second, using plain js `firstChild`

```js
var array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
  .map(i => i.firstChild.textContent.trim())
console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one
    <ul>
      <li>one one</li>
      <li>one two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done regardless of the tag names. Select your parent.

It gives an array of strings with no duplications for parents and their children.

```
$('parent')
.find(":not(iframe)")
.addBack()
.contents()
.filter(function() {return this.nodeType == 3;})
.map((i,v) => $(v).text())
```